# Whats wrong with this line?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4, hidden

My app crashes when I press the "own" button. I don't know what's wrong with my code. I'm new to this, so if I totally screwed up, don't be to hard please :). EDIT: This is what Xcode says:

```
    #1  0x000144fd in -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] ()
```

The app crashes on the line:

```
   if (thing.hidden == NO) {
```

This is the code that belongs to "own":

```
    - (IBAction)own {

if (thing.hidden == NO) {

int rNumber = rand() % 4;

switch (rNumber) {
    case 0:
        result.text  = @"A";
        break;
    case 1:
        result.text = @"B";
        break;
    case 2:
        result.text = @"C";
        break;
    case 3:
        result.text = @"D";
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

}
if (thing.hidden == YES) {
    int rNumber = rand() % 3;
```

Comment: which line does it crash on? what is the crash message?

Comment: What's the error in debug window?

Comment: Paste the full code. Also paste the console logs.

Comment: Do you think your rNumber returns the right value ? Kindly show us your traceback Error...

Comment: I would rather suggest him to use int r = arc4random() % 4;

Comment: Are you sure you set the right action for your own button? are you setting the action in nib file or programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

There may be several rason

IBAction is actually just a hint that tells interface builder where to find the methods in your objects so you can link controls to methods.

In iOS, actions can take zero, one or 2 parameters.

If one parameter, that parameter is the object sending the message:

```
-(IBAction) someAction: (id) sender;
```

If two parameters, it takes the form:

```
- (IBAction) someAction:(id) sender forEvent: (UIEvent*) event;
```

you can use -(void)own and connect to your button in nib file

Answer (score 0):

Nothing seems wrong in your code, assuming that the objects *thing* and *result* are **retained properly**.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)own {

if (thing.hidden == NO) {

int rNumber = rand() % 4;
NSString *myText = @""; // 
switch (rNumber) {
    case 0:
        myText  = @"A";
        break;
    case 1:
        myText = @"B";
        break;
    case 2:
       myText = @"C";
       break;
    case 3:
       myText = @"D";
       break;
   default:
       break;
}
result.text = myText;
}
if (thing.hidden == YES) {
    int rNumber = rand() % 3;
```

Comment: See comment above. Should I still use your code or can I keep my own?

Comment: there is nothing wrong in your code except 'sender' param to your IBAction. you can use mine as well there is nothing wrong except little bit modification

Comment: I'm new to posting my own questions on stackoverflow, how can I set my question to answered?

Comment: you can write the comment of your question, you can not i guess you have not enough reputation to answer of your question

Answer (score 0):

I just met this question. It's because of the memory management, I send the button related action to a released  viewController. Hope this help.(BTW,I use the arc mode)